Sending RTF body messages to Outlook with MimeKit and Mailkit
Im currently working with MailKit and Mimemessage in sending emails with "plain","html" and "rtf" bodies. Although I am having an issue with sending an email with an rtf body. As the email received, converts the rtf content into an attachment of an unknown type. Any suggestions as to how I can work around this? I have attached the code base im working with as well below.
`
var message = new MimeMessage();
                
 message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey", "joey@sendrtf.com"));
 message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Yash", "yash@sendrtf.com"));
 message.Subject = "How you doin?" + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

                
              


 string rtfBody = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;} This line is the default color\line \cf2 This line is red\line \cf1 This line is the default color}";
                

                // Create an RTF part with correctly formatted content type and charset
var rtfPart = new TextPart("rtf")
         {
            Text = rtfBody
                   
         };
message.Body = rtfPart;
SendMail(message); //this will just connect to the client and send the message 


When Outlook sends in the RTF format (which is not a standard MIME format), it packs PR_RTF_COMPRESSED property (and quite a few other MAPI properties that cannot be converted to MIME) in the winmail.dat attachment in the TNEF format.
Not sure why you want the RTF format, which Microsoft itself has been de-emphasizing for years now.
